# jquery - Update a variable outside a animate function, dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about updating a variable outside a function dynamically, then being able to use it another function for example. In this situation the user presses the right key and moves 50px.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

<title>Barry bounce</title>

<script src="js/plugins/charinfo.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div id="canvas">

  <img src="img/characters/BarryBall.png" id="barry" alt="">


</div>

</body>

<!-- jquery here -->

<script> 

var barryPosX;
var state = 0;

function getCurrentPos(position) {
  barryPosX = position.left;

};


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 39:
      $("#barry").stop().animate({
        left: '+=350'
      }, function() {
          position = $("#barry").position();
          getCurrentPos(position);
            if(barryPosX > $("#canvas").width()) { 
              state = 1;
              console.log(state);
            }

      })
    break
    case 37:
      $("#barry").stop().animate({
        left: '-=350'
      });
    break
  }
})

    if (state == 1 ) {
    console.log(state);
}


</script>
```

I don't understand why the console isnt logging '1' when the image goes beyond a the 'canvas' div width .. any ideas?

Comment: Call `getCurrentPos()` outside of `keydown` event handler?

Comment: I am looking to update the barryPosX global variable with the current position of $barry, every time the user presses the right key

Comment: @guest271314 see edit

Comment: `barryPosX = getCurrentPos();` does not appear to be necessary; you should be able to just call `getCurrentPos()`

Comment: @guest271314 please check edits, I have given an example of 'if' statement which doesn't seem to work. It might give you a greater understanding of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: stack overflow just went down, did your comment go through?

Comment: The edit you just posted should work, does it not?

Comment: It does not, when I move the image outside the div, it does not seem to produce a '1' in the console :S this has been my problem

Comment: @bonafido see edit

Comment: Without having a working demo in Codepen or JSFiddle it's hard to help you debug this any further, since it's directly related to a CSS issue. Only other thing I can add is, in jQuery position() gives the offset of an element relevant to its parent container, and in the case of left the values increase as the element moves to the right inside of the parent container.  So to exceed the width of the canvas, the img will need to move to the right of the canvas element. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, you can remove the last if()... statement at the bottom of the page. It's only being executed when the page loads, so it will never evaluate to true. Not that it's hurting anything by being there, but just so ya know.

Comment: yes thats the answer i needed ! obviously i need an event to trigger it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

barryPosX is already in the global scope, so you can just assign the value to barryPosX directly in the getCurrentPos function just like you've done. You don't need to assign the value to barryPosX from within the animation callback.

If you wanted, you could also pass the value into the getCurrentPos function like so:

```js
var barryPosX;

function getCurrentPos(position) {
  barryPosX = position.left;
};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 39:
      $("#barry").stop().animate({
        left: '+=50'
      }, function() {
          position = $("#barry").position();
          getCurrentPos(position);
      })
    break
    case 37:
      $("#barry").stop().animate({
        left: '-=50'
      });
    break
  }
})
```

The value of barryPosX will also be accessible within the changeScreen function.

Comment: could you please look at my edits, although I feel you are correct. When the state variable is set to 1, id like to perform the example if statement

Comment: stack overflow just went down, did your comment go through?